# Unmanaged memory jamming cluster during dask's merge_asof method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to merge large dataframes using `dask.dataframe.multi.merge_asof`, but I am running into issues with accumulating unmanaged memory on the cluster.

I have boiled down the problem to the following. **It essentially just creates some sample data with timestamps using dask, converts to pandas dataframes, and then runs dask's `mergea_asof` implementation.** **It quickly exceed the memory of the workers with unmanaged memory and eventually the cluster just gets stuck** (it does not crash, just stops doing anything).

It looks like this:

[image: It looks like this]

```
from distributed import Client, LocalCluster    
import pandas as pd
import dask 
import dask.dataframe 

client = Client(LocalCluster(n_workers=40))

# make sample datasets, and convert them to pandas dataframes 
left = dask.datasets.timeseries(start='2021-01-01', end='2022-12-31', partition_freq="3d").reset_index().compute()
right = dask.datasets.timeseries(start='2021-01-02', end='2023-01-01', partition_freq="3d").reset_index().compute()
left = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(left, npartitions=250)
right = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(right, npartitions=250)       

# Alternative to above block (no detour via pandas)
#left = dask.datasets.timeseries(start='2021-01-01', end='2022-12-31', partition_freq="3d").reset_index()
#right = dask.datasets.timeseries(start='2021-01-02', end='2023-01-01', partition_freq="3d").reset_index()   

# (dask crashes on datetime, so convert to int first)
left['timestamp'] = left['timestamp'].values.astype('int64')    
right['timestamp'] = right['timestamp'].values.astype('int64')        

dask.dataframe.multi.merge_asof(
    left=left.sort_values(by='timestamp'),
    right=right.sort_values(by='timestamp'),
    tolerance=pd.to_timedelta(10000000, unit='seconds').delta,
    direction='forward', 
    left_on='timestamp',
    right_on='timestamp',    
    ).compute()
```

Note that I deliberately call `compute()` on the sample data to get pandas dataframes, since in the final use case I also need to start from padnas dataframes, so I need to "model" that step as well.

Interestingly, not making this detour works much better. So if I outcomment the first data creation code block and use the one labelled as an alternative instead, then the merge is successful (still some unmanaged memory, but not enough to stop the cluster)

While I suspect that occupying machine memory by the local pandas dataframe may increase the unmanaged memory (?) the data size is far from taking all of the machine's RAM (200 GiB). So my questions are

1. Why does the cluster hang despite memory being available on the machine?
2. Why does using pandas dataframes intermittently affect memory management during merge_asof?

I have tried various things with regard to garbage collection, thinking there might be some pandas data sticking around in memory while merge_asof is executed, but to no avail. I have also tried garbage collection on the workers, as well as automatic and manual memory trimming, as described in [this blog post](https://coiled.io/blog/tackling-unmanaged-memory-with-dask/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwR6iGR0mb0), neither of which showed any effect worth mentioning.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I am having exactly the same issue, and have tried all these alternatives, but still do not manage to have my queries executed.

Comment: @Roxana  No, I did not solve it. As far as I remember I had to work around it by adjusting the size of the worker memory, but unfortunately I do not recall specifics except that it was a less than ideal solution. Sorry. In case I revisit the issue and find a better solution I will post it here.